# Self-energy diagram using feynmp

Tags: feynman, feynmp

Please, could you help me to draw such a diagram? [image: diagram]

The straightforward code I use is just this:

```
\begin{fmffile}{diagr_6th_ord}
\begin{fmfgraph}(200,125)
\fmfleft{i}
\fmfright{o}
\fmf{photon}{i,v1}
\fmf{photon}{v4,o}
\fmf{photon}{v2,v3}
\fmf{photon}{v5,v6}
\fmf{fermion}{v1,v2}
\fmf{fermion}{v6,v4}
\fmf{fermion}{v3,v5}
\fmf{dashes_arrow}{v1,v5}
\fmf{dashes_arrow}{v3,v4}
\fmf{dashes_arrow}{v6,v2}
\fmfdotn{v}{6}
\end{fmfgraph}
\end{fmffile}
```

But this doesn't work. I suppose this is wrong for the same reason as, e.g. in order to add a bubble diagram I should write something like `\fmf{photon, left, tension=0}{v5,v6}` rather than just `\fmf{photon}{v5,v6}`, but I don't know how to fix my froble.

Also, I need an arrow for a photon (wiggly line). I know that in order to do this I can use the following code

```
\fmfcmd{%
style_def wiggly_arrow expr p =
cdraw (wiggly p);
shrink (2);
cfill (arrow p);
endshrink;
enddef;}
```

Could you tell me where I should put it?

Comment: Although not very satidfactory, I have the following solution to the first part of my question                                                       \begin{fmffile}{my_training} 
\begin{fmfgraph}(150,75) 
\fmfleft{i1,i2}
\fmfright{o1,o2}
\fmf{phantom}{i2,v5,v6,o2}
\fmffreeze
\fmf{phantom, right}{i1,v1,v2,v3,v4,o1}
\fmffreeze
\fmf{photon}{i1,v1}
\fmf{photon}{v5,v6}
\fmf{photon}{v2,v3}
\fmf{photon}{v4,o1}
\fmf{fermion}{v1,v5}
\fmf{fermion}{v2,v6}
\fmf{fermion}{v3,v4}
\fmf{dashes_arrow}{v1,v2}
\fmf{dashes_arrow}{v5,v3}
\fmf{dashes_arrow}{v6,v4}
\end{fmfgraph}
\end{fmffile}

Comment: Ok, I probably have a quite not bad answer to the first question \begin{fmffile}{6th_ord}
\begin{fmfgraph}(250,50)
\fmfleft{i1,i2}
\fmfright{o1,o2}
\fmf{phantom}{i2,v5,v6,o2}
\fmffreeze
\fmf{phantom}{i1,v1,v2,v3,v4,o1}
\fmffreeze
\fmf{photon}{i1,v1}
\fmf{photon}{v5,v6}
\fmf{photon}{v2,v3}
\fmf{photon}{v4,o1}
\fmf{fermion}{v1,v5}
\fmf{fermion}{v2,v6}
\fmf{fermion}{v3,v4}
\fmf{dashes_arrow}{v1,v2}
\fmf{dashes_arrow}{v5,v3}
\fmf{dashes_arrow}{v6,v4}
\fmfdotn{v}{6}
\end{fmfgraph}
\end{fmffile}

Comment: And to the second question \begin{fmffile}{diagr1}
\fmfcmd{%
style_def wiggly_arrow expr p =
cdraw (wiggly p);
shrink (1.2);
cfill (arrow p);
endshrink;
enddef;}
\begin{fmfgraph*}(100,60)
\fmfleft{i1}
\fmfright{o1,o2}
\fmflabel{$\hat{a}$}{i1}
\fmflabel{$\sigma^{-}$}{o1}
\fmflabel{$\hat{D}$}{o2}
\fmflabel{$g$}{v1}
\fmf{wiggly_arrow}{i1,v1}
\fmf{fermion}{v1,o1}
\fmf{dashes_arrow}{v1,o2}
\fmfdotn{v}{1}
\end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile}

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please expand the code snippet that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). A MWE should compile and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem. it's much easier to help you if we have full working code to start from.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to both questions is

```
\begin{fmffile}{6th_ord_SE} 
\fmfcmd{%
style_def wiggly_arrow expr p =
cdraw (wiggly p);
shrink (1);
cfill (arrow p);
endshrink;
enddef;}
\begin{fmfgraph}(160,30) 
\fmfleft{i1,i2}
\fmfright{o1,o2}
\fmf{phantom}{i2,v5,v6,o2}
\fmffreeze
\fmf{phantom}{i1,v1,v2,v3,v4,o1}
\fmffreeze
\fmf{wiggly_arrow}{i1,v1}
\fmf{wiggly_arrow}{v5,v6}
\fmf{wiggly_arrow}{v2,v3}
\fmf{wiggly_arrow}{v4,o1}
\fmf{fermion}{v1,v5}
\fmf{fermion}{v2,v6}
\fmf{fermion}{v3,v4}
\fmf{dashes_arrow}{v1,v2}
\fmf{dashes_arrow}{v5,v3}
\fmf{dashes_arrow}{v6,v4}
\fmfdotn{v}{6}
\end{fmfgraph}
\end{fmffile}
```

Comment: I tried it, but I don't get the required image.

Answer (score 1):

One does not even have to play with the styles:

```
\begin{fmfgraph}(200,125)
\fmfleft{i1,i,i2}
\fmfright{f1,o,f2}
\fmf{phantom}{i1,v5,v6,f1}
\fmf{phantom}{i2,v2,v3,f2}
\fmffreeze
\fmf{photon}{i,v1}
\fmf{photon}{v4,o}
\fmf{photon}{v2,v3}
\fmf{phantom_arrow}{v2,v3}
\fmf{photon}{v5,v6}
\fmf{phantom_arrow}{v5,v6}
\fmf{fermion}{v1,v2}
\fmf{fermion}{v6,v4}
\fmf{fermion}{v3,v7,v5}
\fmf{dashes_arrow}{v1,v5}
\fmf{dashes_arrow}{v3,v4}
\fmf{dashes_arrow}{v6,v7,v2}
\fmfdotn{v}{6}
\end{fmfgraph}
```

[image]